# Calculating time difference in C (days, hours, minutes, seconds)

Tags: c, time, date-arithmetic

I've tried to calculate the time difference between days / hours / minutes / seconds but the result is not good.
I tried to lower them  and then turn them in seconds, then I brought them back to the same format(D/H/M/S).
My target is that to calculate time spent, between two times. Like: 
1Day, 2Hours, 3Minutes and 54 seconds and
3Days, 3Hours, 10 Minutes and 23 seconds.
Here is what i`ve tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int day1, hour1, min1, sec1, day2, hour2, min2, sec2, totalTime;
    printf("Enter input:");
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &day1, &hour1, &min1, &sec1, &day2, &hour2, &min2, &sec2);
     totalTime = (day2-day1)*86400 + (hour2-hour1)*3600 + (min2-min1)*60 + (sec2-sec1);

     printf("D: %d\n", totalTime / 86400);
     totalTime = totalTime % 86400;

     printf("H: %d\n", totalTime / 3600);
     totalTime = totalTime & 3600;

     printf("M: %d\n", totalTime / 60);
     totalTime = totalTime % 60;

     printf("S: %d\n", totalTime);

    return 0;
}
```

But don`t work as i expected.

Comment: aghhh...how do you know scanf was a success in first place?

Comment: ...and if the dates are in different months?

Comment: What do you mean 'scanf was a succes' and i don t want to calculate difference more than 30 days

Comment: What is your exact input? He means, if `scanf` successfully matched all items see [manpage of scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Always check the return value of a function!

Comment: 27th February to 4th March is less than 30 days.

Comment: Typo: `totalTime = totalTime & 3600;` ==> `totalTime = totalTime % 3600;`

Comment: Time conversion is hard! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this is a poor way to calculate time difference, there are two problems:

1. scanf cannot separate integers
2. hour difference is wrong

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int day1, hour1, min1, sec1, day2, hour2, min2, sec2, totalTime;
    printf("Enter input:");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &day1, &hour1, &min1, &sec1, &day2, &hour2, &min2, &sec2);
    totalTime = (day2 - day1) * 86400 + (hour2 - hour1) * 3600 + (min2 - min1) * 60 + (sec2 - sec1);

    printf("D: %d\n", totalTime / 86400);
    totalTime = totalTime % 86400;

    printf("H: %d\n", totalTime / 3600);
    totalTime = totalTime % 3600;

    printf("M: %d\n", totalTime / 60);
    totalTime = totalTime % 60;

    printf("S: %d\n", totalTime);

    return 0;
}
```

A better way to calculate time difference could be by using [difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/) function

Comment: What do you mean by "time difference is wrong"? It would be helpful to point out exactly where the typo is in the code, it is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I wrote "hour difference is wrong" because in your code, line 14, `totalTime = totalTime & 3600;` is wrong. It should be `totalTime = totalTime % 3600;`